# ASP.NET Dynamically add rows into existing Table while looping through XML nodes

Tags: asp.net, xml

What im trying to do is to populate an empty Table with cells and the number of cells per row is 4 and the number of all cells is the number of nodes in btnNode

The empty table ID = "MainTable"
and so far i created this but it seems i get an error in

TableRowCollection rows = new TableRowCollection();

has no constructors defined.Searched in google and didnt find help to solve this issue

Here is my code :

```
private void linkBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
                string text = btn.Text.ToString();
                XmlDocument clickDoc = new XmlDocument();
                clickDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ProductShow.xml"));
                XmlNodeList btnNode = clickDoc.SelectNodes("products/" + text.ToString() + "/*");
                int count = btnNode.Count;

                TableRowCollection rows = new TableRowCollection();

                if (count < 4)
                {
                    TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count / 4; i++)
                    {
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }

                }

                int j = 1;
                foreach (XmlNode node in btnNode)
                {


                   //TableRow row = new TableRow();

                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.CssClass = "Cell";

                    LinkButton linkbtn = new LinkButton();
                    linkbtn.Text = node.InnerText;
                    linkbtn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    Image img = new Image();


                    cell.Controls.Add(linkbtn);
                    cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
                    cell.Controls.Add(img);

                    rows[j].Cells.Add(cell);





                    j++;

                }
                foreach (TableRow row in rows)
                {
                    MainTable.Rows.Add(row);

                }






        }
```

Comment: Can't you just add each new `TableRow` to `MainTable.Rows`? That way you don't have to create *temporary* `TableRowCollection`..

Comment: because I must find the rows in different loop after that and its a hard way to find them can you give me some tips for how to do that